# CSS table data is being squashed(?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a scrollable table. But my result shows the table data being squashed(?) or sort.

[image: Any help?]

I am not sure why the snippet shows fine. But for me, it shows exactly like the picture whenever I refresh the page.

This is the code that I have been working so far.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 40px 40px 40px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: max-content;
}

.content-table thead tr {
  background-color: #3cd45d;
  color: white;
  display: table;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 63px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content-table tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 193px;
}

.content-table tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.content-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.content-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3cd45d;
}
h1 {
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.button1,
.button2,
.button3,
.button4,
.button5,
.button6 {
  background-color: #3cd45d;
}

.logo-img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 65px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin-left: 248px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/employee.css" >

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/cyberview.png"/>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Employee</title>
</head>

<div class="grid-container">
      <div>
          <h1>Performance</h1>
    
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="button button1">Add</button>
            <button class="button button2">Edit</button>
             <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Filter by....
              <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Date</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Timing</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <br>
    
    
          <table class="content-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Achievement</th>
              <th>Training</th>
              <th>Skills</th>
              <th>Education</th>
              <th>Reviews</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Daniel</td>
              <td>s</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>s</td>
              <td>l</td>
              <td>s</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Brown</td>
              <td>s</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>s</td>
              <td>l</td>
              <td>s</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Kevin</td>
              <td>s</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>s</td>
              <td>l</td>
              <td>s</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>John</td>
              <td>s</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>s</td>
              <td>l</td>
              <td>s</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Shaun</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>D</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In CSS, I have used inline-block to fix the {th} and {td} to be fixed and aligned

Comment: It's hard to tell what you should do without being able to reproduce the issue. Are there other styles loaded in the page that might conflict with the CSS of the table.

Comment: I am not sure, but if i search any css elements on the web console and turn off and on, it works..